# StaleElementReference Error Element not found in the cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm using Capybara 2.1 with Ruby 1.9.3 using the selenium driver (with Minitest and Test Unit) in order to test a web app.

I am struggling with the `StaleElementReferenceException` problem. I have seen quite a number of discussions on the topic but I haven't been able to find a solution to the issue that I am facing.

So basically, I'm trying to find all pagination elements on my page using this code:

```
pagination_elements = page.all('.pagination a')
```

Then I'm doing some assertions on those elements like:

```
pagination_elements.first.must_have_content('1')
```

After those assertions, I'm continuing the test by clicking on the Next Page link to make sure that my future first pagination element will be the Previous Page.
To do that I'm retrieving paginations elements again :

```
new_pagination_elements = page.all('.pagination a')
```

And the Stale Error is occurring here, because I'm reaching elements that I've already reached. ( [Here is the error](https://gist.github.com/Tb0/7522672079d9087f59d2) )

You can see the link states [here](http://imgur.com/a/rJy5e).

I really have no idea how to make this common test work properly.
Do you have any tips for a better way to reach my pagination elements?

Comment: Please look into https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/843

Comment: @RajarshiDas I've already read this topic and related ones, but it's a really old issue, from a previous version of Capybara, and it doesn't help with my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes have some problem with AJAX intensive pages, in my case this workaround solves it:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
  sleep 1
  retry
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the main message in the gist is:

```
Element not found in the cache - 
perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

I have similar case before. There are two solutions:

1. Add `page.reload` before checking same stuff in new page, if you have set `Capybara.automatic_reload  = false` in `spec_helper`
2. `find` a special element in new page which previous page doesn't have. This effect is equivalent to wait.

Another method is to use specific selector. For example, instead of

```
pagination_elements = page.all('.pagination a')
```

Use

```
pagination_elements = page.all('#post_123 .pagination a')
```

Append a unique id area to the selector and you should not meet such problem.

Comment: I would love to avoid the use of page.reload because my integration tests are following user's flow, and reloading a page is not a part of it.

Comment: @Evers, nothing wrong here. The default setting is `true`, so every action will reload the content, you just havn't noticed it. I always set it `false` because I user Javascript to interact frequently. Forget this part if you don't have such setting in `spec_helper`

Comment: But a force to `reload` may help if you check same things twice. Worth to try.

Comment: Thanks! It works pretty well now!  Appending a unique ID is a better way to do it. Launching this specific test 10 times only results in one failed test. So it's still not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting link about this error and how to fix it : http://stefan.haflidason.com/testing-with-rails-and-capybara-methods-that-wait-method-that-wont/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in addition to race conditions, this error also appears due to misused `within` blocks. For example:

```
within '.edit_form' do
  click '.edit_button'
  # The error will appear here if the 'edit_button' is not a
  # descendant of the 'edit_form'
end
```

Comment: that's my case! I was locked inside a `within` block that was causing a faux error on stale object inside of it - what was stale wasn't what I was `#find`'ing, but instead the block itself!

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried to use WebDriver directly rather than via Capybara?  This woudl potentially give you more control of when to and when to not cache objects.

e.g.  (Apologies for the java syntax but should get the idea)

```
WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("input.foo"));

searchField.click();

searchField.sendKeys("foo foo");

System.out.println(searchField.getText());

//Do something elsewhere on the page which causes html to change (e.g. submit form)

.....
....

//This next line would throw stale object

System.out.println(searchField.getText());

//This line will not throw exception

searchField = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("input.foo"));

System.out.println(searchField.getText());
```

Assigning "findElement" again to "searchField" means that we re-find the element. Knowing when to and when not re-assign is key went deciding how to cache your webelements.

I have not used Capybara, but I assume that it hides the caching strategy from you?

Comment: We are already using Capybara on our other projects and we are not considering to roll back to the Webdriver itself. Capybara save us a lot of time. But you are right, capybara has caching strategies, among a lot of others :)

Comment: I am about to move to Ruby and am trying to decide on which library to use.  It is things like this which make think I will just use Webdriver directly.  I like to be in control too much to use something like Capybara

Comment: I'm a great defender of Selenium Webdrivers, but I have to admit that Capybara is great to wait for elements ect ... Letting you focus on your tests.